# Scrolling a line graph horizontal in IOS Charts

Tags: ios, swift

I am using IOS Graphs to develop an application that represents set of data on a line graph. I am trying to represent large sets of data on the graph however due to the small width of the iPhone screen this leads to the graph getting compressed and looking ugly, most of the labels also disappear. Is there a way to create a large line graph that would support all the data sets without compressing the graph and have the user scroll horizontally to view more portions of the graph?

I was thinking that a horizontal scroll viewer could do the job however Swift doesn't have such object, only a vertical scroll viewer. Any ideas?

Thank you

Comment: You can use a UIScrollView. It has horizontal scroll.